# IBM Content Manager worklists, is there a way to get all packages when return count is limited

Tags: db2-content-manager

The worklist involved has a limit on return items since it is so large via the CM admin. Using the Java API, when I do a `routingService.getCount(worklist,owner)` it gives me the count of all packages in the worklist.  When I do the `routingService.listWorkPackagePidStrings(worklist,owner)` it gives me the collection but it is limited to the count set by the admin.  Sort of what you would expect.  But I need all of the packages when running with the API's.

I can get all of the work packages if I do the following, but it doesn't seem like a good idea to temporarily change the limit count for the worklist:

```
workList.setMaxResult(0);
routingMgmt.update(workList);       
dkCollection dkcollection = routingService.listWorkPackages(worklistnameI, userName);
workList.setMaxResult(25);
routingMgmt.update(workList);
```

Tried to use this prior to the `listWorkPackages`:

`routingService.getDocRoutingServiceMgmt().retrieveWorkList(worklist).setMaxResults(0)`

but this didn't affect the returned packages.  Anybody have another suggestion to bypass the worklist return limit while using the API's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second approach can not work. 
`routingService.getDocRoutingServiceMgmt().retrieveWorkList(worklist).setMaxResults(0)`

Once the worklist is retrieved setMaxResult has no effect. As far as I know there is no way to re-retrieve the worklist after a new maxResult was set.

Because I think that there are valid reasons for limiting the max return results, you must take some kind of workaround. 
I think that your approach is quite acceptable. Maybe you could think about to wrap it in an explicit transaciont to ensure the limit will always be set back to 25.